# file_get_contents in other folders

Tags: php

I have this folder structure:
- classes
    Tasks.php
- configs
    tasks.json

I need to get the file data tasks.json from the classes folder

```
    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->userdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('.\configs\tasks.json'), true);
    }
```

I tried to indicate the paths of another kind (through the full path)

In response, I get either an empty array or **Warning: file_get_contents(/configs/tasks.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...**

Comment: Well going up a directory is .. not . so try changing that to '..\configs\tasks.json'

Answer (score 1):

I think you have supplied the wrong path, try this

```
$this->userdata = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/configs/tasks.json'), true);
```

If your PHP files reside classes dir use

```
$this->userdata = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../configs/tasks.json'), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to go one dir up from Tasks.php, use:

```
public function __construct($user_id)
{
    $this->userdata = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../configs/tasks.json'), true);
}
```

Comment: @A.Dobriy It actually worked, because your code no longer emits warning. And also `json_decode()` returns an array, which is good. Why the array is empty is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->userdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('../configs/tasks.json'), true);
```